Office Script to Copy Rows From One Worksheet To Another
I have a shared excel workbook on SharePoint that is being used by a few users. This sheet tracks reach outs to counties across the United States. When a reach out turns into a lead it then gets copied to a separate worksheet to expand on from there. I attempted to write a script that would accomplish this but failed miserably. What I am trying to accomplish with this script is in the "US Counties" worksheet, column O will have the option to move that row to the "RSR" worksheet. The script would then copy data from that row and place it in a new row in the "RSR" worksheet. There is a little shift in the columns between sheets which I have mapped out in the table below. Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.




RSR Worksheet Column Letter
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z
AA
AB
AC
AD
AE
AF
AG
AH
AI
AJ




US Counties Worksheet Column Letter
A
B






G
H
L
M
N








P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z
AA
AB
AC
AD




How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.

|     RSR   Worksheet Column Letter     | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z | AA | AB | AC | AD | AE | AF | AG | AH | AI | AJ |
|:-------------------------------------:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|:--:|
| US   Counties Worksheet Column Letter | A | B |   |   |   |   |   |   | G | H | L | M | N |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | P | Q | R | S | T |  U |  V |  W |  X |  Y |  Z | AA | AB | AC | AD |

colString is the mapping rule of columns. 0 means skipping the column.
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const usSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("US Counties");
    const psrSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("PSR");
    const colString = "1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,8,12,13,14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30";
    const arrCol = colString.split(",");
    // load source data table
    const usValues = usSheet.getUsedRange().getTexts();
    const targetCol = 15 // Col O
    const targetVal: string = "Done" // target row to move
    let iRow = -1;
    let resVals:string[]=[]; 
    // loop through data rows
    for(let i=1; i<usValues.length; i++){
        // check target value
        if(usValues[i][targetCol-1] === targetVal){
            // expected data row
            let rowVals: string[] = [];
            iRow++;
            for(let j=0; j<arrCol.length; j++){
                if (arrCol[j] === "0"){ // skip cols
                    rowVals.push("");
                } else { // extrac val from source table
                rowVals.push(usValues[i][parseInt(arrCol[j])-1])
                }
            }
            resVals.push(rowVals)
        }
    }
    // console.log(resVals)
    // get the count of rows on dest. sheet
    const usedRowCnt = psrSheet.getUsedRange().getRowCount();
    // write output to sheet
    psrSheet.getRangeByIndexes(usedRowCnt, 0, resVals.length, arrCol.length).setValues(resVals);
}

